# php in array question

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code here:

```
if (in_array('mystring', $entry->getCategories()->getValues()))
{
   ... //do somethingA
```

This works.

However, I want to allow somethingA to run, if "mystring" OR "mYstring" or "MYSTRING" is the case.

So I've tried like so:

```
if (in_array(array('OCC', 'OCc','Occ', 'occ', 'ocC','oCC', 'oCc', 'OcC'), $entry->getCategories()->getValues()))
{
```

But I get nothing returned. What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: Well, what does getValues() return?

Comment: @Pekka - it's a string as expected so I guess. (true, I haven't dump them, I just thought that the problem will be on this in_array miss use. and apparently it was. Lucky guess, and I should have dump it more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`in_array()` cannot compare the values of two arrays, nor can it compare strings case-insensitively. From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> If *`needle`* is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.

You can try this trick instead. Map `strtolower()` to the categories array so everything is in lowercase, then search the array for the lowercase string:

```
$cats_lower = array_map('strtolower', $entry->getCategories()->getValues());

if (in_array('mystring', $cats_lower))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Let me forever be known as the guy who put you over 20k. Nice answer by the way. xD

Answer (score 1):

Something which is more future proof (try including all possible combinations of long strings), try:

```
if (in_array(strtolower('myStrIng'), array_map(strtolower, $entry->getCategories()->getValues()))) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($entry->getCategories()->getValues() as $val) {
  if(preg_match("/$val/i", "occ") {
    somethingA();
  }
}
```